# c# Razor Pages, EF Core, How do I generate and add Child Records through Code to a Parent Record that has yet to be added using

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I'm using c# Razor Pages with EF Core 5. I am not using MVC at all. I am trying to auto generate child records (months of the year) for a parent record (Year with Start Date/End Date). My model has the relations set up in them:

```
namespace Seasons.Models
{
    public class AccountYears //Parent Record
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public Guid AccountYearsID { get; set; } 
            

        [Display(Name = "Accounts Year Name"), Required]
        public string AccountYearsName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Start Date"), Required, DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "End Date"), Required, DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }

        //AccountYearsMonths
        public List<AccountYearsMonths> AccountYearsMonths { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Seasons.Models // Child Records
{
    public class AccountYearsMonths
    {

        // [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public Guid AccountYearsMonthsID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid AccountYearsID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Month Name"), Required]
        public string AccountYearsMonthsName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Start Date"), Required, DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "End Date"), Required, DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }

        //AccountsYears
        public AccountYears AccountYears { get; set; }

    }
```

And then my AccountYears Create Page - Note the page has only fields for the parent to fill in when I create, I am wanting to generate all the child records in the code and save the whole transaction in one go.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using MyApplication.Data;
using Seasons.Models;

namespace Seasons.Areas.Setup.Pages.FinanceAccountYears
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly MyApplication.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public CreateModel(MyApplication.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
//            _context.Attach(AccountYearsMonths);
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public AccountYears AccountYears { get; set; }
        public List<AccountYearsMonths> AccountYearsMonths { get; set; }

        // public List<AccountYearsMonths> AccountYearsMonths { get; set; }


        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            

            //AccYearsMonths();

            //var emptyAccountYears = new AccountYears();
            //if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<AccountYears>(
            //        emptyAccountYears,
            //        "AccYears",
            //        ay => ay.AccountYearsID, ay => ay.AccountYearsName, ay => ay.DateStart, ay => ay.DateEnd, ay => ay.Status))
            //{
            //    _context.AccountYears.Add(emptyAccountYears);

            AccYearsMonths();

            _context.AccountYears.Add(AccountYears);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            //Guid AddedID = AccountYears.AccountYearsID;

            //AccYearsMonths(AddedID);

            //_context.AccountYears.Update(AccountYears);
            //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }


        public void AccYearsMonths()
        {

            // AccountYearsMonths = new List<AccountYearsMonths>();

            DateTime MasterStartDate = AccountYears.DateStart;
            DateTime MasterEndDate = AccountYears.DateEnd;
            
            // Get the StartDate, MonthEndDate, and YearEndDate into variables

            DateTime Date1 = new DateTime(MasterStartDate.Year, MasterStartDate.Month, 01);
            DateTime Date2 = new DateTime(Date1.Year, Date1.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(Date1.Year, Date1.Month));
            string MonthName = new string(Date1.ToString("MMM"));
            

            while (Date1 < MasterEndDate)
                {

                AccountYears.AccountYearsMonths.Add(new AccountYearsMonths
                {
                    AccountYearsMonthsName = MonthName,
                    DateStart = Date1,
                    DateEnd = Date2,
                    Status = "OPEN"
                });

                //AccountYearsMonths d = new AccountYearsMonths
                //{
                //    AccountYearsMonthsName = MonthName,
                //    DateStart = Date1,
                //    DateEnd = Date2,
                //    Status = "OPEN",
                //    AccountYearsID = YearID

                //};

                // _context.AccountYearsMonths.Add(d);
                // AccountYearsMonths.Add(d);


                if (Date1.Month > 11)
                {
                    Date1 = new DateTime(Date1.Year + 1, 01, 01);
                }
                else
                {
                    Date1 = new DateTime(Date1.Year, Date1.Month + 1, 01);
                } // Endif
              
                Date2 = new DateTime(Date1.Year, Date1.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(Date1.Year, Date1.Month));
                MonthName = Date1.ToString("MMM");

            } // End While

           

        } //End AccYearMonths


    }
}
```

I get the following error when I run this code: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Which occurs when it runs this line: AccountYears.AccountYearsMonths.Add(new AccountYearsMonths

As you can see by all the commented out code I have tried a few different ways.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Somehow I cannot get the model to recognise that the AccountYearsMonths are children of the AccountsYears table. And even if I try create the children with the GUID of the parent, the model still does not recognise the child records. - The only info I can find on here are all to do with MVC which in this case I am only using Razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need initiallize the `AccountYearsMonths` object like below:

```
while (Date1 < MasterEndDate)
{
     //change here...
    AccountYears.AccountYearsMonths = new List<AccountYearsMonths>();

    AccountYears.AccountYearsMonths.Add(new AccountYearsMonths
    {
        AccountYearsMonthsName = MonthName,
        DateStart = Date1,
        DateEnd = Date2,
        Status = "OPEN"
    });
    //....
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!! The trick was I was missing the //change here...
    AccountYears.AccountYearsMonths = new List<AccountYearsMonths>();. However I moved it outside of the loop. When the declaration was inside the loop it was only creating one month. Placing the declaration before the loop then allowed me to build the list of months!!! So I wasn't marrying the parent to the child by only declaring AccountYearsMonths without the AccountYears. prefix. Many, many thanks @Rena !!!